# Power consuming on suspend

Tags: suspend

It seems that my laptop (14Z980) resumes immediately after entering S3.

Have tried editing `/proc/acpi/wakeup`

(only `PWRB      S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0C:00`)

but problem still not solved.

It consumes about 10% for 7-8 hours during suspending (during suspending, the Power button blinks and the monitor is off, I see no difference comparing to Windows sleep).

On Windows, it consumes 0% for 10 hours sleeping.

On ChromeOS, it consumes 0% for 10 hours suspending too, so I'm really confused.

I'm on `5.3.0-46 generic`, `Kubuntu 19.10`. Tried upgrading the kernel to the latest version or downgrading it to `4.20.17` or `4.14.175`, see no difference.

Tried disabling TLP, see no difference too.

Plz help me :(

> ```
> [ 1133.506432] PM: suspend entry (deep)
> [ 1133.512105] Filesystems sync: 0.005 seconds
> [ 1133.513617] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
> [ 1133.516562] OOM killer disabled.
> [ 1133.516562] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
> [ 1133.518280] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
> [ 1133.521553] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from [MY_MAC_ADDRESS] by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
> [ 1133.540358] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
> [ 1133.541407] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
> [ 1133.838239] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
> [ 1133.891720] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
> [ 1133.896014] ACPI: EC: event blocked
> [ 1133.896014] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
> [ 1133.896015] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
> [ 1133.896031] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
> [ 1133.897447] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
> [ 1133.900200] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
> [ 1133.901762] IRQ 127: no longer affine to CPU3
> [ 1133.902773] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
> [ 1133.905776] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
> [ 1133.907349] IRQ 123: no longer affine to CPU5
> [ 1133.907356] IRQ 129: no longer affine to CPU5
> [ 1133.908360] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
> [ 1133.909886] IRQ 124: no longer affine to CPU6
> [ 1133.910896] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
> [ 1133.912486] IRQ 125: no longer affine to CPU7
> [ 1133.912495] IRQ 139: no longer affine to CPU7
> [ 1133.913505] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
> [ 1133.916954] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
> [ 1133.917040] ACPI: EC: EC started
> [ 1133.917040] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
> [ 1133.927105] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
> [ 1133.927152] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
> [ 1133.927153] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
> [ 1133.927958] CPU1 is up
> [ 1133.928007] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
> [ 1133.928645] CPU2 is up
> [ 1133.928673] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
> [ 1133.929310] CPU3 is up
> [ 1133.929337] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x1
> [ 1133.930100] CPU4 is up
> [ 1133.930131] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x3
> [ 1133.930771] CPU5 is up
> [ 1133.930799] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x5
> [ 1133.931452] CPU6 is up
> [ 1133.931479] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x7
> [ 1133.932145] CPU7 is up
> [ 1133.935176] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
> [ 1133.944336] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
> [ 1133.962133] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
> [ 1133.962134] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
> [ 1133.966013] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
> [ 1133.987772] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
> [ 1133.989631] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
> [ 1133.998353] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
> [ 1134.104986] nvme nvme0: 8/0/0 default/read/poll queues
> [ 1134.131235] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
> [ 1134.198676] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
> [ 1134.234325] usb 1-6: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
> [ 1134.305949] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
> [ 1134.307954] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
> [ 1134.382398] usb 1-5: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
> [ 1134.532675] acpi LNXPOWER:00: Turning OFF
> [ 1134.532763] OOM killer enabled.
> [ 1134.532764] Restarting tasks ... 
> [ 1134.542315] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
> [ 1134.543661] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 26 week 38 2015
> [ 1134.544666] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 16
> [ 1134.544667] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
> [ 1134.544668] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
> [ 1134.544669] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
> [ 1134.544670] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
> [ 1134.544671] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
> [ 1134.544932] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-12-16.sfi
> [ 1134.550081] done.
> [ 1134.578765] PM: suspend exit
> ```

Comment: Seems a kernel issue. Did you still happen? Tried a live distro? Draining the battery to 0% are killing its lifespan. Maybe `journalctl -xk -p warning` could provide more info